# Iterating through a 2D list using another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array

The code below seems to be iterating through a 2d list using another list which conceptually doesn't make much sense to me. 
What would be the in range equivalent to the code below, using lens as I'm finding it quite difficult to understand.

I've changed the variable names as I'm working on coursework but if its too abstract I can add in the original variable names.

```
#list2 is a 2d list
#list1 is a normal list
for list1 in list2
for k in range(n) #n and k are constants
#any if statement
```

Comment: You should format your code a bit nicer, using indenation and adding colons after the `for`. Also, it is not clear what exactly `n` (or `k`) is. In my answer below I have assumed that `n` is the length of `list2`.

Comment: n and k are unrelated constants, I didn't mean to leave that in. It was there from where I was changing variable names

Comment: As it is stated below, the value of list1 before the first `for` statement does not matter. It loops through the elements of list2 (list2 is a 2D list = a list of 1D lists), assigning the value to the variable list1 (making it a 1D list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "2D" list is just a list where each element is itself a list. To access each element of the lists inside the "main" list, do

```
for list1 in list2:
    for element in list1:
        print(element)
```

If you want a version using `range`:

```
L2 = len(list2)
for i in range(L2):
    list1 = list2[i]
    L1 = len(list1)
    for j in range(L1):
        element = list1[j]
        print(element)
```

As should be clear from the above, using `range` in a for loop is very rarely a good idea, as the code is much less readable.